# which -a rails generates duplicate ouputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After solving this issue, and after I followed the solution: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/1106

Nothing worked for me, so I ended up running `sudo gem install rails`.
Everything's fine but when running `which -a rails`, I get duplicate outputs:

```
glenn@Glenns-MBP proj-api % which -a rails
/Users/glennposadas/.rbenv/shims/rails
/Users/glennposadas/.rbenv/shims/rails
/Users/glennposadas/.rbenv/shims/rails
/Users/glennposadas/.rbenv/shims/rails
/usr/bin/rails
```

Question is, how do I clean these duplicates up?

EDIT:
PATH:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

ECHO PATH:

> /Users/glennposadas/.rbenv/shims:/Users/glennposadas/.rbenv/shims:/Users/glennposadas/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/glennposadas/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/glennposadas/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/glennposadas/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/glennposadas/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/glennposadas/Library/Android/sdk/emulator

Comment: Can you include your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: @jad see edit. thansk!

Comment: Solving which issue? In any case, if there are multiple paths to the same executable, maybe `which` is resolving them? Why is this a problem, though?

Comment: that `PATH` doesn't look like I was expecting.  can you `echo $PATH`?

Comment: Please see the edit again, @jad. But I think dave is right, this shouldn'e be considered a problem.

Comment: Duplicated entries won't break anything, but they're a sign there's duplication in your actual `PATH`.

Comment: A more readable version of your path is available via `gem env`.

Comment: yep, there's duplication in your `PATH`, which you could fix by updating it, but as @DaveNewton said, it shouldn't cause a problem, as long as the `rails` is the right one